# How can i make my pagination button active?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a pagination navigation and I want pagination button to be active when user is on that page. 
Here is how I use pagination code:

```
<?php if ($totalPages > 1) { ?>
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
    <li class="page-item">
        <?php echo "<a class='page-link' href='index.php?page=1'>First page</a>"?>
    </li>
    <?php
        for ($i=2; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
            echo "<a class='page-link' href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
        }

    ?>
    <li class="page-item ">
        <?php echo "<a class='page-link' href='index.php?page=$totalPages'>Last page</a>"?>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php } else { ?>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: how do you know the current page number?

Comment: from url. From there i will get page value

Comment: by means of php or js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for ($i=2; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
       echo "<a class='page-link ".($i == $currentPageNo ? "active"  : "" ). "' href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  }
```

**Try this**

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a collection like this:

`$data = Model::paginate(10);`

Then, in your view, you can use the following to create a pagination with numbers and auto `active` class in Laravel.

`{{ $data->links() }}`

**OR**

You can pass a variable from your controller like:

`$active = true;`

and in your view you can do something like this:

`<a href="somelocation" class="{{ @if($active) acctive @endif }}"> #Link </a>`

Comment: Look at the `OR` section, if you can send a boolean variable to the current page, then you can mark that page as `active` by checking for the variable with `@if` and add a css class to it.

Answer (score 0):

Before displaying pagination link check if that page no and current page no is same or not. If it is same then add class active to that.For e.g.:

```
for ($i=2; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
    if ($i == $currentPageNo) {
        echo "<a class='page-link active' href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a class='page-link' href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
    }
}
```